# Create several arrays from an array, by an attribute. Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array with this structure.

```
[  
 {  
  "ticketCod":"DF20172002284",
  "operationDate":"2017-11-15 00:00:00",
  "action":"G+",
  "note":null,
  "ubicacion":"Z27252\\TR2",
  "ubicacion_id":2974295,
  "cd":3883279
},
{  
  "ticketCod":"DF20172000288",
  "operationDate":"2017-09-19 00:00:00",
  "action":"G+",
  "note":null,
  "ubicacion":"56286\\TR1",
  "ubicacion_id":2978697,
  "cd":3884701
},
{  
  "ticketCod":"DF20172000288",
  "operationDate":"2017-09-19 00:00:00",
  "action":"G-",
  "note":null,
  "ubicacion":"56286\\TR1",
  "ubicacion_id":2978697,
  "cd":3884701
},
{  
  "ticketCod":"DF20172000810",
  "operationDate":"2017-10-06 00:00:00",
  "action":"G+",
  "note":null,
  "ubicacion":"56286\\TR1",
  "ubicacion_id":2978697,
  "cd":3884701
 }
]
```

I need to create as many array as there are different "cd" in the array.

In this case I would have an array with the three values that "cd" has 3884701 and another array with the value that "cd" has 3883279.

It has to be something in a loop, since the array is much larger and can have more "cd" different.

The application has "lodash": "~ 3.10.1",

Comment: So where are you stuck. All you'd need to do is reduce the array into an object keyed off `cd` with your sub arrays

Comment: Sounds like you want `_.groupBy(data,'cd')`. Show what you have tried as well as expected results

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Post an example of your expected output.

Comment: I'm not an expert in javascript, I would need something similar to a Java Map. In which each different "cd" would be a key, and the value would be an array with all the objects with that same "cd". Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cds = _.groupBy(vm.maniobrasPropuestas,'cd');
    angular.forEach(cds, function (cd, key) {
      console.log(cd);
      angular.forEach(cd, function (mani, key) {
        console.log(mani);
        //my code
      });
    });
```

Thank you charlietfl